# Why are get submodules not on any branch?

Tags: git-submodules

I have a project with git submodules. I do a checkout with `git clone --recursive`. When I do this, I get this error on the submodule:

```
$ cd submodule
$ git status
# Not currently on any branch.
$
```

What I would like to do is to have the submodule automatically put on the master branch, because I frequently work in the submodule. Is there any easy way to do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is not an error. It just indicates that the submodule is in "detached head" mode.
The reason is that the superproject's git link points to a specific commit of the submodule and not a specific branch. So the recursive clone checks out that commit directly.

If you want to work on branch master of the submodule:

```
git checkout -t origin/master
```

Comment: Thanks. Is there a way to link the superproject to a specific branch?

Comment: Not what I know of. But it would be wrong anyway, as a certain commit of the superproject would not define a consistent state, as the branch of the submodule can move.